# Flutter Text is weird in before "\n" thai language

Tags: flutter

Flutter 3.10.5

Dart SDK version: 3.0.5

I wrote the code like this now, if it's text with "\n" before it, text will behave weird except for the after "\n" .

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'ไก่จิกเด็ก\nไก่จิกเด็ก',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you please let me know on which platform are you running app? in my case i tried with the given code it's working properly in mobile app

Comment: I run in web app

Comment: i have same problem too. have you solved the problem? my text doesn't have `\n`. but, if you look at the screen, line breaks are automatic.

Comment: I verify to flutter team in this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/127379 and waiting for response

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is as follows:

```dart
SafetyText('ไก่จิกเด็ก\nไก่จิกเด็ก');
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SafetyText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle? style;

  final String _pattern = '\n';

  const SafetyText(
    this.text, {
    Key? key,
    this.style,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textList = text.split(_pattern);
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: textList
          .map(
            (value) => SizedBox(
              child: Text(value, style: style),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```